# OpenLayers 3 and XYZ Layer

Tags: javascript, cors, openlayers-3

I have a map, which I want to display.
It consists of a standard map (OSM, Google or Bing) and a layer, provided by Openseamap.org.
This layers produces seamarks as images for a map.
This should look like this (more or less, without the pink screen):
[image: OpenSeaMap Screen with OpenLayers2]

I am trying to transfer this to OpenLayers3.

The JavascriptCode I used is:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'http://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                crossOrigin: 'null'
            })
        })],
    view: new ol.View2D({
        center: ol.proj.transform([12.1, 54.18], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 13
    })
});
```

Which is called by the Map:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2KBC/) to experiment with. I just can't seem to get the SeamarkLayer working, although Firebug tells me, when they don't find the seamarks as images, like in the screen with the pink square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the CORS header of tiles.openseamap.org.
The solution is the following, thanks to some help on GitHub of the OpenLayers3!

The resource from `http://tiles.openseamap.org` are not cross-origin compatible.
Two options: enable the [cross-origin resource sharing at the server level](http://enable-cors.org/) or switch to a canvas map ([see updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2KBC/1/))

Answer (score 2):

To me, the problem is solved by removing the quotes of *null*:

```
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'http://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            crossOrigin: null
        })
    })]
```